# How to run a specific javascript file on Heroku server?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a javascript file that I use in Nodejs to populate my database with fake data. So in my project folder I do:

```
node fakedata.js
```

which populates my database with fake data. I deployed my website to heroku and I want to be able to run the same javacript in my heroku database. Is there a way to run javascript file like this on the heroku server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple:

```
heroku run node populateData.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcourse !
You can edit your `Procfile` as follows

```
web: node fakedata.js && <Your App Startup Command>
```